# Drag with mouse to place multi-cursors on subsequent lines in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

On the [Batch Rename extensions's marketplace page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JannisX11.batch-rename-extension&ssr=false#overview) a user is shown dragging with their mouse from the top to the bottom of a text file, placing a multi-cursor on each line. How exactly are are they doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the modifier `Shift+Alt`

No need to drag with the modifier:

- `Click` in the first line
- `Shift+Alt+Click` in the last line

Comment: Though it does work with dragging, too

Answer (score 1):

This is done by clicking and dragging with the middle button on your mouse. You can also use Ctrl+Alt+Up/Down on a keyboard.